# How to Track the updated values and input names in a form via Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I am working on a SAAS platform where i want to keep a record of the all changes made by the sub-admins. For eg if some edit something then i want to save those updated values to a log table and track who updated what and when.

So can some tell me how can i clone a form when it loads and then keep all the updated values only.

I got this function after some search but i don't know what exactly this does.

```
function isModifiedForm(form){
  var __clone = $(form).clone();
  __clone[0].reset();
  return $(form).serialize() == $(__clone).serialize();
}
```

Comment: You should do a server-side comparison between the new values submitted and what is in the record at that point, because if you keep the original values in a client-side form the user could change things via the browser's dev tools.

Comment: ^ Agreed. This is server logic that really shouldn't be done on the client.